# merging CSV files in Hadoop

Tags: csv, hadoop, merge, apache-pig

I am new to the Hadoop framework and would really appreciate it if someone could walk me thru this.

I am trying to merge two .csv files.

The two files have the same headers are orderd the same, etc.

The thing is that I have no idea how to merge these files to one and then clean the empty lines and unused columns.

Answer (score 3):

> The two files have the same headers are orderd the same etc

Since the files are the same, you can upload them to the same directory.

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /path/to/input
hdfs dfs -put file1.csv /path/to/input
hdfs dfs -put file2.csv /path/to/input
```

HDFS will natively treat these as "parts of a single file" if you read from `hdfs:///path/to/input`

**Note**, you'll want to strip the header from both files before placing them into HDFS in this fashion.

Another option would be to concatenate the files locally. (Again, remove the headers first, or at least from all but the first file)

```
cat file1.csv file2.csv > file3.csv
hdfs dfs -put file3.csv /path/to/input
```

After that, use whatever Hadoop tools you know to read the files.

Comment: It seems that the `hadoop fs -getmerge` tool can merge the files with the same header, only keeps the header from the first file. That way you don't need to strip the header.

Comment: I was under the impression that it just copied all file contents together. It isn't smart enough to detect matching file headers.

Answer (score 0):

Since they have the same structure,load them both using PIG into 2 relations and then UNION the 2 relations.Finally you can FILTER the records that match certain criteria.I am assuming the files have 2 fields each for simplicity.

```
A = LOAD '/path/file1.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (a1:chararray;a2:chararray);
B = LOAD '/path/file2.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (b1:chararray;b2:chararray);
C = UNION A,B;
D = FILTER C BY (C.$0 is NULL OR C.$1 is NULL) <-- If first or second column is null filter the record.
DUMP D;
```